# Necessarily the case that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int f_n\,dx \le \int \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative Lebesgue measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Is it necessarily true that$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int f_n\,dx \le \int \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n\,dx?$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Deleted, because I was no more sure. What exactly do you mean by wrong direction?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I mean that Fatou's lemma gives you something like the opposite inequality

Comment: This is true if you have an integrable dominating function $\phi$, i.e., $|f_n| \leq \phi$ for all $n$ and $\int \phi \, dx < \infty$. Then you can use the Fatou's lemma to $\phi - f_n$ to prove the statement. This is sometimes called as [*Reverse Fatou's lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma).

Comment: @SangchulLee Exactly what I meant. It was used in a proof I currently went through.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek interesting, I'd forgotten about that

Answer (score 0):

It is not.  In particular, take $f_n(x) = 1_{[n,n+1]}$.  Then the left side comes out to $1$, but the right comes out to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

No, for $$f_n:=\mathbf 1_{[n,n+1]}$$
we have $\int f_n=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ so $$\lim \sup \int f_n=1.$$ However  $\lim \sup f_n=0$ thus $$ \int\lim \sup f_n=0.$$